# sklearn Import error: cannot import name tfidfvectorizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
    /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, *where)
    173             else:
    174                 filename = fname
--> 175             __builtin__.execfile(filename, *where)

     /home/sayghosh/doc.py in <module>()
     9 
     10 from sklearn.datasets import load_mlcomp
---> 11 from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
     12 from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
     13 from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix

     ImportError: cannot import name TfidfVectorizer
```

I am getting this error when I am trying to run this [code](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/mlcomp_sparse_document_classification.html)

Comment: It works fine on my machine. Have you tried executing only that line? Also, what is your version `sklearn.__version__`?

Comment: Hi Ray, my sklearn.__version__ is '0.10'. I have tried running only that line and it doesnt work. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Maybe you try to update to at least `0.13`? Because the doc is for `0.13+`.

Comment: Good to hear! Keep working!

Comment: @Ray - how do you manage your library versions ? Initially, I was using apt-get install <libraryname>, which gave me older versions. Now I downloaded the source code and added it to PYTHONPATH as documented here [link](http://novieq.blogspot.in/2013/12/how-to-get-started-with-scikit-learn-in.html). Do you do it the same way or is there some better approach ?

Comment: Maybe `apt-get upgrade`? Not familiar with that ha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping up the discussion in the comments to have Stack Overflow remove this question from the list of unanswered questions:

The solution is to install a more recent version of scikit-learn (0.13 or later). Apparently the original poster was using an old version of Debian or Ubuntu that shipped scikit-learn 0.10 as specified in the `sklearn.__version__` package attribute.

Answer (score 0):

For the later versions, you can find vectorizers and transformers like TfidVectorizer in `sklearn.feature_extraction.text`

Answer (score 0):

First uninstall your current version of `scikit-learn` with the following syntax

```
$ pip uninstall scikit-learn
```

use the below syntax to install a new version of `scikit-learn`

```
$ pip install scikit-learn==0.13
```